# cx_freeze error when I try to include images

Tags: python, image, compilation, pygame, cx-freeze

When I try to `build` my game compiler I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gamecomp.py", line 22, in <module>
    executables = [exe])
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 365, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 929, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 948, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 948, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 234, in run
    metadata = metadata)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 104, in __init
__
    self.includeFiles = self._ProcessPathSpecs(includeFiles)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 384, in _Proce
ssPathSpecs
    raise ConfigError("target path for include file may not be "
cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: target path for include file may not be an absolu
te path
```

My compiler is:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"], "include_files":["C:\Documents and Settings\boot_1.bmp", "C:\Documents and Settings\boot_2.bmp", 'C:\Documents and Settings\boot_3.bmp', 'C:\Documents and Settings\boot_4.bmp', 'C:\Documents and Settings\fish1.bmp', 'C:\Documents and Settings\fish2.bmp', 'C:\Documents and Settings\fish3.bmp', 'C:\Documents and Settings\fish4.bmp', 'C:\Documents and Settings\goldenfish_1.bmp', 'C:\Documents and Settings\goldenfish_2.bmp']}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

exe=Executable(
     script="game.py",
     base=base
     )

setup(  name = "Game name",
        version = "1.0",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [exe])
```

If I don't use `include_files` I can compile the game without any errors, but others can't play the game.
How can I compile my game without errors / fix errors?

Comment: Not sure about cx_freeze, but the error say it must be a dict and you pass a list

Comment: You need to add `"include_files": includefiles` to the `build_exe_options` dict, not the options dict.

Comment: See what hapends then(I updated my questione).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it now.

I have to write: `"boot_1.bmp"` instead `"C:\Documents and Settings\boot_1.bmp"` and so for all other pictures.

I also have to change it in the game code.

Comment: I'm glad you've found a fix - it turned out there was also a bug in cx_Freeze, because putting the whole path should have worked for freezing (you probably needed to change your game code anyway). I've [submitted a fix](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/pull-request/53/fix-processing-path-specs-from-config-when/diff).